# With "frombody" attribute, parameter of Web Api method recieves null value while testing it with Postman

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, postman

Given below is my WebApi method, and I want to test it with Postman, but whenever I submit the request, *myKey* always contains the null value.

```
[Route("Complete")]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Complete([FromBody]string myKey)
{
    // My logic
}
```

And this how I am submitting the request via Postman.
[image]

I have found many post suggesting how can we submit the data from Web but not a single one showing same using Postman.

Can you please guide me to get the value of *myKey* via Postman tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass just the value from the request body. When you add the `[FromBody]` attribute for a simple type parameter like `string`, the body will be read as string.

[image]

Comment: this saved my entire day! I was struggling for passing int array and this one gave me idea!